# Random Camera appeared after i've done some animation

Tags: animation, camera, dopesheet, random

I just finished creating an animation for my character, but i then i decided to play the animation through the camera view and it ended up showing me a random camera view that i don't have in my scene. i even deleted all other cameras i have and it still shows this random camera view. im pretty sure it has something to do with the photo below. the "camera" is also directly below my character. im not sure how to get rid. Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: This is an indicator that you did a "Bind camera to marker".   select this marker and use the DELete key.  Then in the Scene properties, be sure you have your desired, primary camera listed in the "Camera" text box

Answer (score 0):

It looks by the name of your camera like you have selected an armature as camera, you must have selected it and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> by accident, you can remove it as camera in the *Scene panel > Camera*. As for the marker you show in the timeline, you can create one with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> and remove with <kbd>X</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for providing a clear answer! Its been fixed now and everything is back to normal. Appreciate you taking the time to help me out!